# How to persist an object in webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

As I'm self taught my VB coding is not bad but my use of OOP is poor. I'm sure this can be done but I have not found out how yet.

I am building a webforms app which needs to grab data about a user from AD. I have a Person Class which I can use as follows

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim LoggedOnPerson As Person        'Added here so available throughout class
    Private strLoggedOnUser As String
    Private strADDomain As String
    Private strADUserID As String

    Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        strLoggedOnUser = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").ToUpper
        strADDomain = strLoggedOnUser.Split("\")(0)
        strADUserID = strLoggedOnUser.Split("\")(1)

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            'Dim LoggedOnPerson As Person   *** changed to
            LoggedOnPerson = New Person
            'Get details from AD for logged on user
            LoggedOnPerson.GetDetails(strADDomain, strADUserID)
            'Store in Session
            Session("LoggedOnUser") = LoggedOnUser
            'This will now give me access to details such as
            'LoggedOnPerson.EmailAddress
            'LoggedOnPerson.GivenName
            'LoggedOnPerson.TelephoneNo etc.
        Else
            'Postback so pull in details from Session
            LoggedOnUser = Session("LoggedOnUser")
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

My problem is that I cannot access LoggedOnPerson in other events. e.g.

```
Public Sub SaveDetails()

    Dim email As String = LoggedOnPerson.Email 
    'This now produces correct result. No error that LoggedOnPerson is not declared

End Sub
```

I of course get LoggedOnPerson is not declared error. How can I get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the object of "Person" inside Page_Load event. Take it outside and declare at the class level. Also add that object to view state/session state on Page_Load event and typecast it to "Person" class inside other events.

Comment: Thanks... I have updated my original code to reflect your suggestion. Seems to work... Testing.

Comment: When you start typing "LoggedOnPerson" you should be able to see it in intellisense. If you cannot then you should understand that object is not available for that scope which is generally the problem. Also try and find out when to use view state and when to use session state. It is more related to sensitive data sending to the client and size of request/response. Anyways happy coding!

Comment: Samar.. Am I right in thinking ViewState is not sent to client and Session is?

Comment: Its the opposite. Viewstate is sent to the client and session state is not.